# Git Commit Hash of Last Commit excluding merges

Tags: git

I am trying to get the Git commit hash of the last commit excluding merge commits.

I understand that the following command gets the commit hash of HEAD:

`git rev-parse HEAD --short`

However, if the last commit was a merge, I get the hash of that commit instead. This is a problem because I am using a CI/CD tool to tag artifacts with the commit hash, and can't have any differences due to merging Pull Requests.

Is there any way to get the last **code change** commit?

Comment: Do you already know that HEAD refers to a merged commit?

Comment: Yes, the head will refer to the merged commit, not the last commit with code changes

Comment: then: `git show HEAD^2` should give you the commit before merging, is that what you need?

Comment: I don't think that would work in all cases.  Sometimes there are nested merge commits in develop branch, and then when merging to master you would have to check several commits back.  Perhaps there is a way to prevent merge commits from showing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, this is the command that will take the latest commit *excluding* merges

`git rev-list --no-merges -n 1 HEAD`

Answer (score 1):

You can get commit's short hash with command that log last commit with format and flag to omit merges:

```
git log -n 1 --no-merges --pretty=format:%h
```

How it works:

- command `git log -n 1` get last commit (you can also use shortcut `git log -1`, but in my opinion it's less readable),
- next you need to omit merges, su use `--no-merges` flag,
- and finally set format with short hash (`'%h'` stands for *abbreviated commit hash* in [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats)).

---

Why previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57701325/2442133) with `git rev-list` doesn't suit for me? Because it show long hash when I need it short (I think topic author needs it the same because he tries with `--short` flag).

I can add format in the same way as in `git log` command:

```
git rev-list --no-merges -n 1 --pretty=format:%h HEAD
```

But it logs long hash AND short hash below.

Comment: Whilst your answer may solve the OP's problem, please try and provide an explanation as to how/why your answer will help. Posting code-only answers doesn't do a good job of explaining and sharing knowledge to others.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I thought that `git log` command with parameters is enough readable, but probably any coder that doesn't explain thinks that and forgot it about some days. And previous answer was accepted so I thought it's resolved. But it doesn't suit for me so I paste my solution. I edited with explanation.